# Poisson Distribution- Method Of Moments

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like to ask if there is a way to determine if the Poisson distribution is a suitable model for the description of my data by using the method of momenets.

For example i have this problem:

Τhe weekly number of accidents for a period of 30 weeks in a specific area are :
8 ,0 ,0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 12, 5, 
1, 8, 0, 2, 0, 1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 
3, 3, 4, 7, 4, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2.
How can i prove with the method of moments that these data follows Poisson distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you cannot exactly "prove" that the data follows a Poisson distribution. You can only, using a better word, "test" that the data comes from a Poisson distribution of mean, let's say $\lambda$.

Here is what I would do:

First, calculate the mean of all your observations. In other words, let $\left\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{30}\right\}$ be all your observations and then calculate the mean $\bar{x}$ where $\bar{x}=\frac 1{30}\sum_{r=1}^{30}x_r$. You should know that in this case, $\bar{x}=\hat{\lambda}$ where $\hat{\lambda}$ is the **estimated** parameter of your model based on the data. Then, use tests like the chi-square goodness of fit test or the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to "stress-test" your model, ie see if the data indeed comes from this distribution with this parameter.

Alternatively, you can use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to determine the parameter $\lambda$ of the Poisson distribution. Then, if you want to test for other values of the parameter $\lambda$ then use tests like the likelihood ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

The variance of a Poisson distribution is equal to its mean so a quick and dirty method is to check if this relationship approximately holds.